# batch converting from XLS to windows CSV on a mac

Tags: macos, mac, batch, csv

I'm using OS X and have lots of these XLS files that I need to format as a batch operation. I need them in "Windows CSV" format, but I can only seem to get them batch converted to Mac CSV... I am pretty novice in programming, but willing to learn. Have been fiddling with Automator for hours and have been working with mac excel's VBA. no luck.

I am using OS 10.6.8

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Download Excel to CSV converter from here : http://www.macupdate.com/download/36172/Excel_to_CSV_Converter1.3.zip

[image]

[Credit goes here](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36172/excel-to-csv-converter)